# sbt package in spark throwing below error

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-spark

I have tried build packge in spark.It's throwing below error.
command: sbt package

```
 [warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.transaction;1.1.1.v201105210645!javax.transaction.orbit
[warn]  :: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.servlet;3.0.0.v201112011016!javax.servlet.orbit
[warn]  :: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.mail.glassfish;1.4.1.v201005082020!javax.mail.glassfish.orbit
[warn]  :: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.activation;1.1.0.v201105071233!javax.activation.orbit
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] {file:/usr/local/spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop1/project/}default-cd4dd9/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: download failed: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.transaction;1.1.1.v201105210645!javax.transaction.orbit
[error] download failed: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.servlet;3.0.0.v201112011016!javax.servlet.orbit
[error] download failed: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.mail.glassfish;1.4.1.v201005082020!javax.mail.glassfish.orbit
[error] download failed: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.activation;1.1.0.v201105071233!javax.activation.orbit
[error] Total time: 386 s, completed Dec 6, 2014 12:53:05 PM
```

**hduser@hduser-VirtualBox:/usr/local/spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop1/project$ cat >simple.sbt**
name := "Simple Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.9.2"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.1.0"

Comment: You may want to ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0"
```